# Posts are printed twice

Tags: posts

I am trying to fetch posts in bootstrap accordion like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) :the_post ();?>
                <div class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed"><?php echo the_title()?></a>
           </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <p><?php echo the_content()?></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
             <?php
              get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
              endwhile;
              twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>
                </div>

    <?php // get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
                </div>
```

My problem is that once post content is printed inside the accordion and once again outside the accordion. How can I prevent the duplication?

Comment: Please do not start your title with "WordPress". This makes no sense on our site. :)

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` includes a template part in your theme where it echoes out the content again. Commenting it out should fix that.

```
<?php
// get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
```